# VUE pass value from checkbox from multiple checkboxes from v-for element

Tags: vue.js

my html

```
<div v-for="(client, index) in clients" :key="index">
    <div>
       <span>{{index+1}} {{client.id}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <div>
          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" :checked="client.IsScreenShot"/>
             <span class="slider"></span>
           </label>
       </div>
       <div>
            <label>
               <input type="checkbox" :checked="client.IsPhotoReport" />
               <span class="slider"></span>
            </label>
       </div>
       <div>
             <label>
                <input type="checkbox" :checked="client.IsShowReport" />
                <span class="slider"></span>
             </label>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" @click.prevent="onChangeAccess(client)">Change</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have multiple checkboxes in div thats coming from v-for and array of data.
Each checkbox is came from data and give true or false value to start position, thats represent value right now.
When user check or uncheck checkbox (it depends want he or not give to client right to see pages on site), I want to take new value from check box and send it to server.
How I can take this new value from each checkbox?
And this is array of div's with three checkboxes in each div, but I need at time only this specific change value from this specific div. I don't need to know if every value in multiple div change. I need to pass only this specific changes value from 1 this div.

For example at first user get 1 div with `first input value true, second - false, third - true`.
Then user change checkboxes to `first input - false, second - true, third - true`.
So when he clicked on button, I need to get value from `first, second and third checkbox and pass it to method`.
How I can get it? any idea please

Comment: I would recommend starting by putting everything inside the outer div into a new component. That would make it much easier to reason about.

Comment: Why? for me its not need, because its just create to complexity

Comment: Nope, to the contrary, it makes it simpler. Right now you need to reason about a list of items. If you move your div to a separate component, you only need to reason about a single item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue is perfect, so I find a great solution, hope it helps someone, I just little correct the code

```
<div v-for="(client, index) in clients" :key="index">
    <div>
       <span>{{index+1}} {{client.id}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <div>
          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" :checked="client.IsScreenShot" @click="client.IsScreenShot = !client.IsScreenShot"/>
             <span class="slider"></span>
           </label>
       </div>
       <div>
            <label>
               <input type="checkbox" :checked="client.IsPhotoReport" @click="client.IsPhotoReport = !client.IsPhotoReport"/>
               <span class="slider"></span>
            </label>
       </div>
       <div>
             <label>
                <input type="checkbox" :checked="client.IsShowReport" @click="client.IsShowReport = !client.IsShowReport"/>
                <span class="slider"></span>
             </label>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" @click.prevent="onChangeAccess(client)">Change</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

God save Vue =)